# Does one need Apple developer's ID to automate iOS devices?

Tags: ios, mobile, automation, webdriver, appium

I am using Appium to automate iOS native and web apps. Do I need to have a developer's ID from Apple to perform automation on iOS devices?

Answer (score 1):

A valid iOS Development Distribution Certificate and Provisioning Profile are necessary to test on a real device. The app will also need to be signed.

You can use debug version .app to run on simulator (without Provisioning). You can find the app file by adding the code

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to deploy your app to iPhone :

Steps :

1. Generate your distribution file with .p12 extension,
2. Generate your
   developer file with .p12 extension. **This step needs the developer
   account.**
3. Generate your distribution .mobileprovisionfile for Ad Hoc
   .ipa file) for the class deployment task (optional)
4. Generate your developer .mobileprovisionfile for Ad Hoc Debug .ipa for the
   end-to-end tests.